# How to make cancel event on-click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Designed collapsible tab and implemented glyphicons for like inline function. When user click on pencil it would turn into the floppy disk is for save the data and another is repeat glyphicon cause when user doesn't fill the data the form should go to the previous state of the page means like back button. Here data save is happening and after save it turning into the the state of pencil. But when i click on repeat glyphicon  it's not going back to previous state of the page. The form is validated with document.getElementById so if i click on repeat also validation is happening. Edited the code. Please anybody at least give me an example how to make onclick previous state of the page. I am beginner i tried something please help me

```js
$(document)
  .ready(
    function() {
      $('.editAddBtn') //class called from html
        .click(
          function() {
            //used to make textbox readonly
            //checks if it is already on readonly mode
            if ($('.editField').is('[readonly]')) {
              //turns the readonly off
              $('.editField').prop('readonly', false);

              //used to make textarea readonly
              $('.mySelect').prop('disabled', false);

              // used to make checkbox disabled
              $('#chk').prop('disabled', false);

              //shown pencil floppy and repeat glyphicon for onclick
              $('.editAddBtn')
                .html(
                  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk">&nbsp;</span>' +
                  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" id="reBtn">&nbsp;</span>'
                ); //Changes the text of the button
              $("#repeatBtn").click(function() { // used to make back state of the form
                $(this).prev().removeAttr("onclick");
                $(this).prev().off("click");
                $(this).prev().on("click", function() {});
              });
            } else { //else we do other things

              <!-- this is used for form validation--> 

              //Form validation
              var cstreet_1 = document
                .getElementById('currentAddressLine1').value;

              if (cstreet_1 == "") {
                document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1')
                  .style.borderColor = "red";
                //return false;
              } else {
                document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1')
                  .style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
              }

              // saveAddress(); //function is used for save the data

              //readonly after filling the data into the textbox t
              $('.editField').prop('readonly', true);

              //readonly after filling the data into the textbox t
              $('.mySelect').prop('disabled', true);

              //readonly after filling the data into the checkbox       
              $('#chk').prop('disabled', true);

              //after saving the data floppy disk turn into the pencil means normal state  
              $('.editAddBtn').html(
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>'
              );
            }
          });
    });
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #b3daff;">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <span style="font-weight: 700;">Addre</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a class="editAddBtn"><span
                  class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="pls" style="color: darkred">&nbsp;</span>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Current
                        </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Address line 1 -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" style="padding-top: 1px;">Address<span
                           style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control editField" id="currentAddressLine1" readonly placeholder="Address Line 1" style='text-transform: capitalize' />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
          </div>
          <!--end tag for address line 1 -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Your coding-style is awful. Hard to read ...

Comment: Add your html. Otherwise it's hard to tell where the problem is. Beside that, your `find` is not correct. You try to find a complete html tag, but find works with selectors. So change `.find('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>')` to `.find('.glyphicon.glyphicon-penci')`.

Comment: Change Onclick event to a function ( `$('#removeBtn').click....` part. )
Then call that function here `<span id="removeBtn" onclick="removefunction()"`

Comment: I am beginner . I tried maximum please help me out. At leaset show me how to come state of previous on click.

Comment: If you want to come to previous state you have to save current state using data attribute or to a local object and when user click on cancel button then again fill the value from that object.

Comment: Previous  state means. When i click on pencil it turn as save and cancel button so save the data is happening. When i click on cancel mans repeat glyphicon the form is not going back instead of that it testing the form validation

Comment: If you only want to change the icon then you can toggle the class rather then changing the html do something like  $('..editAddBtn span').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'); to change it to disk icon and on cancel button click use  $('..editAddBtn span').toggleClass('glyphicon-pencil');

Answer (score 0):

try this code. Although I have commented the saveAddress(); method. uncomment it before use.

```js
$(document).ready(
            function() {
                $('.editAddBtn').click(function() {
                    if ($('.editField').is('[readonly]')) {
                        $('.editField').prop('readonly', false);
                        $('.mySelect').prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#chk').prop('disabled', false);
                        $('.editAddBtn').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk">&nbsp;</span>' + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" id="reBtn">&nbsp;</span>');
                        // $('.editAddBtn span').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk');
                        $(document).on('click', "#repeatBtn",function() {
                        $(this).prev().removeAttr("onclick");
                        $(this).prev().off("click");
                       $('.editAddBtn').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>');
      
                    });
                       
                    } else {
                        var cstreet_1 = document
                            .getElementById('currentAddressLine1').value;
                        if (cstreet_1 == "") {
                            document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1').style.borderColor = "red";
                            //return false;
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1').style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
                        }
                       // saveAddress(); //function is used for save the data
                        $('.editField').prop( //readonly after filling the data into the textbox t
                            'readonly', true);
                        $('.mySelect').prop( //readonly after filling the data into the textbox t
                            'disabled', true);
                        $('#chk').prop('disabled', true);
                        $('.editAddBtn').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>');

                    }

                });
            });
```

```html
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">   
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>       
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #b3daff;">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <span style="font-weight: 700;">Addres</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a class="editAddBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span></a>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="pls" style="color: darkred">&nbsp;</span> </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                                        Current
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Address line 1 -->
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3"
                                        style="padding-top: 1px;">
                                        Address<span
                                            style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control editField"
                                            id="currentAddressLine1" readonly
                                            placeholder="Address Line 1"
                                            style='text-transform: capitalize' />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When i click on repeat glyphicon then also data is on save mode(data is saving). And validation part is not working sir. In between i used document getelementById for validation.

Comment: repeat button code is  $(document).on('click', "#repeatBtn",function() {
                        $(this).prev().removeAttr("onclick");
                        $(this).prev().off("click");
                       $('.editAddBtn').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>');
      
                    });. you can change it as your need. I have provide the way how you can do this. :)